# Trouble with strings and indexOf

Tags: java, string, indexof

If the user types yes, I am trying to create a list(receipt) of everything the user entered between the commas. For example: cat, dog, fish would return: cat dog fish on separate lines. Would I use indexOf?

```
if (language.equals("English")) System.out.println("Please enter your order here (using commas to separate choices!)");

    String order =kboard.nextLine();

        if (language.equals("English")) System.out.println("Would you like a reciept (yes/no)?");

            String response =kboard.nextLine();

                if (response.equals("yes"))
```

Comment: You can use any kind of data structure, like an array, ArrayLists class, Hashmap, etc..

Comment: Look at String.split() or StringTokenizer.

Comment: If you don't actually need the items, and only want to print them, you could do this:
System.out.println(response.replaceAll(",","\n");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your source string is going to be a comma separated list like this, "cat, dog, bug", and you're using java, than I would String.split and set the delimiter to be a ','.

This will return an array of Strings you can then play with like so:

```
String textToParse = "cat, dog, bug";
String[] tokens = textToParse.split(',');
```

You could also use a regular expression but that seems like overkill to me.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `split(parser)` method. Instead of making the input just one string, use an array. For your case, use the following code.

```
String[] order = kboard.nextLine().split(", ");
```

Alternatively, you could do `split(",");` and then use the `trim()` method to remove any extra white space. (You never know how much might be there)

The `split()` method will return an array of strings, which you can now use. So if you wanted to print it out, do something like this:

```
for(String s: order)
    System.out.println(s);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the replaceAll method on Strings.

Say the user enters: "dog, cat, mouse, pussy-cat,"

```
String response = "dog, cat, mouse, pussy-cat,"
//The above line will remove any blank spaces.
String[] userInput = response.split(", ");
```

This will create an array of Strings each index contains the words inputted by the user, in respective order.

Comment: Keep in mind that this is not creating a list of items, as the @op required. It is merely replacing the comma character with newline, which has the same visual result, but not the same flexibility.

Comment: @Paul92 Thanks I have taken the above in to consideration and made appropriate modifications.

Comment: And what if he enters: "dog, cat, gila monster, iguana"? You'd remove the space in 'gila monster'.

Comment: @Kylar it would be ideal for the user to use a hyphen, nevertheless I have mad edits to accommodate such input.

Answer (score 0):

String[] orderArray = response.split(',');

is the way to go. As mentioned by others. Also try to use equalsIgnoreCase when getting yes/no from user.

Comment: It should be `String[] orderArray`, not `String orderArray[]`.

Comment: @mastov Appreciated.Thanks, will keep this in mind. Neat way for code readability.

Comment: @mastov @user489732 Actually, both ways are fine. The `[]` after the name is used mostly by `C` users.

Comment: I know (Ex C++ dev) . But String[] will look more readable. Never thought about it. But I can see beauty of it now.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to avoid trailing and preceding whitespace when splitting, use `response.split(\\s*,\\s*);`.